# How to post a "how to" question on the main site?

Tags: support, questions

I'd like to share some findings on package [`g-brief`](//ctan.org/g-brief), which was designed to write business letters with layout, as used in Germany.

Now, it's not a question I'm about to ask... it's a description of how to make this package work to create serial letters. I'd be presenting the approach from a website I found, with some adaptions to make it more digestible.

Where/how should I post it?

Answer (score 6):

Consider phrasing your "how to manual" in the form of a question. Here's a fictitious start:

> I'd like to create some business letters with layout using the [`g-brief` package](//ctan.org/pkg/g-brief). However, I'm uncertain how to go about it as the documentation isn't clear on what to do and where. I'd like to specifically put X in some specific spot and ensure that Y is always in some other specific spot. How can I achieve this?
>
> Here is a minimal document that I've set up with the information I currently have:
>
> ```
> \documentclass{<class>}
>
> \usepackage{g-brief}
> <more preamble stuff>
>
> \begin{document}
>
> <document stuff>
>
> \end{document}
> ```

Of course, the specifics about the problem should be updated to match what you aim to show.